# select statement with join gone wrong

Tags: c#, sql

I've tried setting my database up as someone suggested, I'm now trying to read some data in but I think my select statement is way off.

I have these 2 tables;

**FilmGenreTable**

```
+----+---------+------+
| filmID | GenreID    |
+----+---------+------+
|  1     | 1          |
|  1     | 2          |
|  2     | 1          |
|  2     | 3          |
+----+---------+------+
```

**filmGenres**

```
+----+---------+------+
| GenreID | Genre     |
+----+---------+------+
|  1      | Drama     |
|  2      | Horror    |
|  3      | Action    |
|  etc    | etc       |
+----+---------+------+
```

**Select statement**

```
SqlCommand genreSelect = new SqlCommand(
SELECT Genre
FROM filmGenres fG
INNER JOIN filmGenreTable fGT
ON fG.[GenreID]     = fGT.[GenreID]
WHERE (fGT.[filmID] = @ID2)", connection);
```

I'm sort of okay with SQL but the values its returning aren't the ones basically! Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

I want to return the Genre's attached to each film using the filmID. So the filmID 1 will return Drama/Horror.

Code:

```
    SqlCommand genreSelect = new SqlCommand("select Genre FROM filmGenres fG INNER JOIN filmGenreTable fGT ON fG.[GenreID] = fGT.[GenreID] WHERE (fGT.[filmID] = @ID2)", connection);
    selectQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID2", filmID);

    using (SqlDataReader reader1 = selectQuery.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader1.Read())
        {
            genres.InnerText += reader1[0].ToString();
            genres.InnerText +=  reader1[1].ToString();
            genres.InnerText +=  reader1[2].ToString();

        }
    }
    connection.Close();
```

Comment: is it mysql ? and if yes mysql does not have syntax as `fG.[GenreID]` ?

Comment: It's SQL/T-SQL in an asp.net/c# website

Comment: Can you, please, explain what is your desired output?

Comment: Can you show what is returned for @ID2=1? And what do you expect to be the return?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say, I want to return the genre names "horror, Drama" using the filmID and the corresponding GenreID in the filmgenretable.

Comment: And the query above returns instead?

Comment: It returns 2 items from a different table

Comment: Perhaps that's correct, could you add the code that tries to read the result and put it on your display controls?

Comment: I don't see how it goes wrong. Are you sure you pass @ID2=1?

Comment: I've added the code I use. Since this is my first using ASP, I have no idea how this select statement works with regards to returning the data selected :X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute a different command, the correct one is the one named `genreSelect` not the one called `selectQuery`.

Said that, you are returning just one field (Genre) but you have two rows (for @ID2=1).
So, to write the results on one line to your output control you need

```
SqlCommand genreSelect = new SqlCommand(@"
         select Genre 
         FROM filmGenres fG INNER JOIN filmGenreTable fGT ON fG.[GenreID] = fGT.[GenreID] 
         WHERE (fGT.[filmID] = @ID2)", connection);
genreSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID2", filmID);

using (SqlDataReader reader1 = genreSelect.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader1.Read())
    {
        genres.InnerText += reader1[0].ToString() + "&nbsp";
    }
}
connection.Close();
```

This explain also why you see data from different tables and why you didn't get an exception when you try to read the reader[1] and reader[2] fields that don't exist in the correct command

Comment: Yeah I mentioned above this is new to me and I wasnt aware of how the statement would behave in terms of returning the data. Also, I've tested the code and is simply returning the movie name from a different table (eh?)

Comment: Or can edit the query to use `STUFF` to prevent `string concatenation`.

Comment: The problem is the command executed. You prepare a command named genreSelect but then you execute a command named selectQuery....

Comment: well thats a piss take! Thanks Steve

Comment: Another copy/paste bites the dust.... :-) If I could have 1cent every time I have failed for that....

Comment: @Steve two SQL questions where I'm convinced its my poor SQL knowledge but just stupid typos you overlook. must be common on stackoverflow I guess! Thanks to all who commented

Answer (score 1):

```
 select a.filmID, a.GenreID, b.Genre from FilmGenreTable a
 inner join filmGenres b on a.GenreID=b.GenreID order by b.Genre
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
SqlCommand genreSelect = new SqlCommand("
    SELECT filmGenres.Genre FROM filmGenreTable 
    LEFT JOIN filmGenre ON filmGenreTable.GenreID = filmGenres.GenreID 
    WHERE filmGenres.GenreID = filmGenreTable.GenreID 
    AND filmGenreTable.FilmID = @ID2", connection);
```

Also make sure you actually declare @ID2:

```
genreSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID2", value);
```

Comment: @ID2 is the parameter.

Comment: ID2 is passed as a parameter after the statement

Comment: The code is working fine, however I'm getting the same results in that its reading in the movie name from a different table?

Comment: Sorted, Thanks Matthijs & Bharadwaj

Comment: Why would you put the join condition " filmGenreTable.GenreID = filmGenres.GenreID " in both the JOIN and the WHERE clause ? It is redundant, and makes the LEFT JOIN become an implicit INNER JOIN.